# Tikz Rotation of an Image to create a trace

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw what is known as the Cantor Target:

I started doing it 'manually' by drawing lots of circles but it is taking far too long. The set is constructed by taking the middle third Cantor set: and rotating it 360 degree around an axis with an end point as the pivot.

Is there a way to do this without a seemingly endless number of circles?

Thank you in advance.

**My code for the middle third Cantor**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals,math}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=Cantor set]
    \draw (0,0) -- (7,0) node[right] {$E_{0}$};
    \draw decorate{ (0,-1) -- (7,-1)} node[right] {$E_{1}$};
    \draw decorate{ decorate{ (0,-2) -- (7,-2)}} node[right] {$E_{2}$};
    \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-3) -- (7,-3)}}} node[right] {$E_{3}$};
    \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-4) -- (7,-4)}}}} node[right] {$E_{4}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: what shoulld it look like?

Comment: Above code is from the manual: page 604.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Cantor Target (possible approximation)]

This iterates the original figure, rotating each iteration by a given angle. The larger the number of cycles, the closer the approximation will be. I've used 1 iteration per degree, so 360 cycles. Increasing this number will increase the quality, but slow the compilation.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    decoration=Cantor set,
    deco/.pic={
      \draw [pic actions] (0,0) -- (7,0) node[right] {$E_{0}$};
      \draw [pic actions] decorate{ (0,-1) -- (7,-1)} node[right] {$E_{1}$};
      \draw [pic actions] decorate{ decorate{ (0,-2) -- (7,-2)}} node[right] {$E_{2}$};
      \draw [pic actions] decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-3) -- (7,-3)}}} node[right] {$E_{3}$};
      \draw [pic actions] decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-4) -- (7,-4)}}}} coordinate [midway] (#1) node[right] {$E_{4}$};
    }
  ]
  \pic [blue] {deco=a};
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using {int(\i/3.6)} ] in {1,...,359} \pic [blue!\j!magenta, rotate around={\i:(a)}] {deco};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## EDIT

However, I suspect that you really only want to iterate the final line of the code from the manual. If you also remove the node, this then approximates concentric circles:

[image: Cantor Target (more probable approximation)]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    decoration=Cantor set,
    deco/.pic={
      \draw [pic actions] decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,0) -- (7,0)}}}} coordinate [midway] (#1);
    }
  ]
  \pic [blue] {deco=a};
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using {int(\i/3.6)} ] in {.5,1,1.5,...,359.5} \pic [blue!\j!magenta, rotate around={\i:(a)}] {deco};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

No doubt there is a more efficient approach!

Answer (score 3):

I guess it is something like this

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \tikz{
        \draw[line width=729]circle(729/2pt);
        \draw[white,line width=243]circle(729/2pt);
        \draw[white,line width=81]circle(243*.5pt)circle(243*2.5pt);
        \draw[white,line width=27]circle(81*.5pt)circle(81*2.5pt)circle(81*6.5pt)circle(81*8.5pt);
        \draw[white,line width=9]circle(27*  .5pt)circle(27* 2.5pt)circle(27* 6.5pt)circle(27* 8.5pt)
                                 circle(27*18.5pt)circle(27*20.5pt)circle(27*24.5pt)circle(27*26.5pt);
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

## Approach 2

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \def\drawwhite#10;{
        \ifnum1#1=1\else
            \draw[white,line width=\a]circle(\b/4pt);
            {\pgfmathsetmacro\a{\a-\b}\pgfmathsetmacro\b{\b/3}\drawwhite#1;}
            {\pgfmathsetmacro\a{\a+\b}\pgfmathsetmacro\b{\b/3}\drawwhite#1;}
        \fi
    }
    \tikz{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\a{243}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\b{2*\a/3}
        \draw[line width=\a]circle(\a/2pt);
        \drawwhite00000000;
    }
\end{document}
```

keep adding 0 if you want to.